# Control access to personal resource using RBAC

Tags: database-design, rbac

I am trying to understand RBAC and then implement one in my project, but currently get confused.

Let's take forum for example. In a forum, member can post a thread, and edit or delete threads they posted. And moderator can also post a thread, and edit or delete any member's threads.

I searched the web, and find a simple model of RBAC, in which there are user, role, and operation, then I have the database schema as below:

```
user(user_id, ...)
role(role_id, ...)
user_role(user_id, role_id, ...)
operation(operation_id, operation, ...)
role_operation(role_id, operation_id, ...)
```

In operation table, I have

```
(..., 'thread/post')
(..., 'thread/edit')
(..., 'thread/delete')
```

and in code, I have

```
if ($user->isPermitted('thread/delete') {
    // delete thread
}
```

It seems fine until that I find every user can delete thread no matter who posted it. To fix it, I may have operation table modified as below

```
(..., 'thread/post')
(..., 'thread/38900/edit')
(..., 'thread/52529/delete')
```

38900 and 52529 are id of thread. And I have to add another table:

```
user_operation(user_id, operation_id)
```

And to give all permissions to moderator (as a role), I have to insert role_operation for every thread posted.

So my question is, using RBAC, how to properly design the database so that members can only edit/delete their own thread, and moderators have the ability to edit/delete any thread?

Comment: You should look into attribute based access control (ABAC). It will do what you are looking for

Comment: @DavidBrossard Yes it is what I had been looking for, thx.

Comment: Great. XACML implements ABAC so check that out too. ALFA is an easy way to implement your policies.